# Displaying Checked column Values in Datagridview checkbox showing data in another form Datagridview

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I have one datagridview(`dataGridView1` which contains a `dataGridview2` column header) in which I have one checkboxcolumn, called `dgvCkb`, in `dataGridView1`. When I uncheck `dgvCkb` in  any row the data of that row should not be shown in another `dataGridview2`(`dataGridview2` is connected to a database(localhost)).

**1st form dataGridview is**:

[image]

**2nd form dataGridview is**:

[image]

My Coding for this:

**form1 coding**

```
private void Customized_column_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn dgvCkb = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    dgvCkb.ValueType = typeof(bool);
    dgvCkb.Name = "Chk";
    dgvCkb.HeaderText = "vis.";
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvCkb);

    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Column";
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Column size";

    string[] row = new string[] {"Date", "103" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    row = new string[] {"Time", "103" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    row = new string[] { "Callee Number", "103" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    row = new string[] { "User", "103" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    row = new string[] { "Called Number", "103" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    row = new string[] { "Department", "103" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    row = new string[] { "Trunk", "103" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    row = new string[] { "City", "103" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    row = new string[] { "Duration", "103" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    row = new string[] { "Pulse", "103" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    row = new string[] { "Amount", "103" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    row = new string[] { "Status", "103" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    row = new string[] { "Callee Extension", "103" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    row = new string[] { "Trunk Port", "103" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    row = new string[] { "Call Type", "103" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

}
```

**form2 coding**

```
String MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                "DATABASE=test;" +
                "UID=root;" +
                "PASSWORD=asterisk";

private void PBX_Logger_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT date as Date,time as Time,user as User,department as Department,trunk as Trunk,city as City,calleenumber as CalleeNumber,callednumber as CalledNumber,duration as Duration,pulse as Pulse,amount as Amount,status as Status,calleextension as CalleeExtension,trunkport as TrunkPort,calltype as CallType from pbx", con);
    con.Open();
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dataTable);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
}
```

I am new to development so looking for solution. please refer me some link.

Thank You

Regards
Dhana

Comment: Have you looked at `DataGridView` events: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, let's assume the form names based on your `Load` method handles match accordingly:

```
Form1.Load += Customized_column_Load;
Form2.Load += PBX_Logger_Load;
```

I have also assumed that you are opening the second form from the `Form1` as follows:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog();
```

As such, the second form just needs access to the first form's grid values. If you pass in that `DataGridView` into the `Form2` constructor, then `Form2` can save it into a variable and recall it during load time - where the rows can be looped through and the size and visibility values are accessed and used on the second form's `DataGridView`:

```
private DataGridView parentDGV;

public Form2(DataGridView parentDGV)
{
      InitializeComponent();
      this.parentDGV = parentDGV;
}

private void PBX_Logger_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

    // Your code to fill the DataSource.

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in parentDGV.Rows)
    {
        string colName = row.Cells["Column"].Value.ToString();
        int size = 0;
        int.TryParse(row.Cells["Column size"].Value.ToString(), out size);

        dataGridView1.Columns[colName].Width = size;
        dataGridView1.Columns[colName].Visible = row.Cells["Chk"].Value != null && (bool)row.Cells["Chk"].Value;
    }
}
```

Lastly, in `Form1`, change your call accordingly:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(dataGridView1);
form2.ShowDialog();
```

This also assumes the following is set in `Form1` too:

```
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

Otherwise you'll need to add some null checks when looping through the rows inside `Form2`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I got an Error in this line :     'dataGridView1.Columns[colName].Visible = (bool)row.Cells["Chk"].Value;'   as  'An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in PBX Logger.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'  now what i do? sorry for trouble.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't account for a row that never had the `CheckBox` column clicked. It would be `null` until that point. See the edit to that line of code in my answer above.